# java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow error in simple gui

Tags: java, swing, jframe, illegalargumentexception, windowbuilder

I am trying to draw a simple GUI (created with windowbuilder in eclipse), I want to have 2 buttons and a scrollable text area between them.  I have created the following code to achieve the above:

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public Font font; //used for the font file
    public JTextArea txtDataWillBe;

     public Main() throws FontFormatException, IOException{
        setTitle("Main title ");

        setBounds(100, 100, 1200, 600);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        txtDataWillBe = new JTextArea();
        txtDataWillBe.setText("Your data will display here");
        txtDataWillBe.setFont(new Font("Droid Sans", Font.BOLD, 18));
        txtDataWillBe.setEditable(false);
        txtDataWillBe.setColumns(1);
        txtDataWillBe.setBounds(0, 40, 919, 484);
        getContentPane().add(txtDataWillBe);

        JButton button = new JButton("CLICK TO OPEN");
        button.setBounds(0, 0, 940, 40);
        button.setFont(new Font("Coalition", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        getContentPane().add(button);

        JButton btnPrint = new JButton("PRINT");
        btnPrint.setBounds(0, 531, 940, 40);
        btnPrint.setFont(new Font("Coalition", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        getContentPane().add(btnPrint);

    }

        private final String JTextFile = null;
        JFileChooser chooser;
        String choosertitle;

        public static File deletefile;
```

EDIT:

```
 public static void main(String s[]) {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Reader");
            Main panel = null;
            try {
                panel = new Main();
            } catch (FontFormatException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            frame.addWindowListener(
              new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    File deleteme = new File (deletefile + "mx.txt");
                    deleteme.delete();
                  System.exit(0);
                  }
                }
              );
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel,"Center");
            frame.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
            frame.setVisible(true);
            }
```

I originally had the JTextarea inside of a JScrollPane (thinking that was the best way to get the scrolling I want working).  I removed the JScrollPane thinking that was causing the console error, but I am still getting the error.

Console output is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
    at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Container.java:439)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1035)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:923)
```

EDIT:  Main added above.

What I am doing wrong with my GUI?
Do I need a JScrollPane and JTextArea to enable vertical scrolling of the loaded text?

Thanks for your help;

Andy

EDIT:

I have edited as per the suggestions below so my code now reads:

```
 public Main() throws FontFormatException, IOException{


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Reader ");
          frame.addWindowListener(
                  new WindowAdapter() {
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        File deleteme = new File (deletefile + "mx.txt");
                        deleteme.delete();
                      System.exit(0);
                      }
                    }
                  );
                frame.getContentPane().add(panel,"Center");
                frame.setSize(getPreferredSize());
                frame.setVisible(true);
```

The rest of the code is as before but all I am getting displayed is a blank grey frame without any of my components (although they are all showing in windowbuilder).

Thanks for the continued help.

Comment: The main is not shown in your sample, but I suspect you're adding your frame to another frame or dialog.

Comment: unrelated: don't do any manual sizing/locating of component, ever. Instead use a suitable LayoutManager.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess the issue with my way of specifying things is that if the user maximises then nothing will draw correctly?  I didnt get on with relative layouts so went to absolutes instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The console output is describing exactly what is wrong here.

```
IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
```

In the line `frame.getContentPane().add(panel,"Center");` you add `panel` into your content pane, but `panel` itself is an instance of `Main extends JFrame`.

You should remove any reference to the outer frame at all and just add the window listener to the `Main` frame, i.e. the main code reduces to something like

```
JFrame frame = new Main();
frame.addWindowListener( ... );
frame.setVisible(true);
```

You may also want to move the `addWindowListener` part inside class `Main`.

Comment: Sorry, I dont quite follow (I am new to Java).  Is the suggestion that I move all of the JFrame frame code up into the Main section?  If you have chance could you give me an example of the modified Main you suggest?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Sorted now pretty much.  Just some tweaking to do.  Thanks.  I have never really understood the ins and outs of Main, its on the list to read up now!